# jquery dynamic loading of external script files before $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have a jqueryUI.js file referenced through a `<script>` tag.
I have several $(document).ready() functions, which use jquery ui functions.

I am trying to load jqueryUI.js file dynamically using $.getScript

I tried the following code...

```
var scriptCntr = 0;
$(document.ready(function(){
    scriptCntr ++;
    $.getScript(path, function (data, textStatus) {
        scriptCntr --;
    });
    while(scriptCntr!=0){
    } 
});
```

on the top of the page.
The idea is to make the $(document).ready() wait till the file is downloaded, but the logic goes to the WaitLoop and stays there indefinitely. The file wouldn't download unless all the $(document).ready() is executed.

Is there a way to download the jqueryUI.js file before the first $(document).ready() is executed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/). This allows you to delay the jQuery's ready event until after the script has loaded.

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("myplugin.js", function() {
     $.holdReady(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for this target:

```
var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
```

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort in this answer, but you should look into deferreds found in 1.5+ check out this article: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/08/24/chaining-jquery-ajax-calls/ from that you can build a chained ajax function that returns a defered object, which much less code and in a much cleaner way

Answer (score 2):

I use `$.getScript()` extensively for scripts that rely on `jQuery` being downloaded first as `$.getScript()` won't instantiate until jQuery is loaded (it's a method of jQuery itself, so can't run unless qQuery has loaded successfully, resolving a jQuery dependency).

A couple of side notes:

- `$.getScript()` forces a download, it **NEVER** uses cached copies.  cane be useful if you always want fresh downloads.  You can use the `$.ajax()` method if you want to enable caching.  This allows a **SIGNIFICANT** performance boost when downloading large files like jQuery-ui on subsequent pages.  I will provide an example at the end of this answer.
- Due to the `$.getScript()` method using the jqxhr model, you can check for a failed script load, and the exception being thrown.  The `$.getScript()` function has a `.fail()` handler attached, you can use it like this...

***using $.getScript()***

```
var urlToLoad = "testLoader.js";

$.getScript("js/slickGrid/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js",function(){
    //  Execute script on successful load
 }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
        //  Code to execute if script fails to load any further
        document.write('FAILED Script Load '+urlToLoad +': '+exception)
    });
```

***using $.ajax()*** *(for caching purposes)*

```
var urlToLoad = "testLoader.js";

$.ajax({
   dataType: "script",
   url: "someurl.php",
   cache: true,
   success: function() {
       //  code to execute on script load success
   }
}).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
        //  Code to execute if script fails to load any further
        document.write('FAILED Script Load '+urlToLoad +': '+exception)
    });
```

I personally write error codes to the screen so I can see the stop point a little easier than in a console, and I have found that console.log output sometimes fails for me depending on my debug software.  Helps a LOT for troubleshooting.  Using this implementation, you can make a simple dependency loader.  Define an array of scripts, execute a function to fire the `$.ajax()` function, and do something when they're all done.  And voila, dependency resolved.  ReuireJAS does this, but it's a set of scripts and additional lod times.  You have jQuery already loaded, so why not do that!

***Example of dependency resolution*** *please keep credits if you use it...* :)

```
/*-----------------------------------
* Script is free to use as long as 
* credits stay attached to script here.

* jQuery Dependency Loader
* created: May 15, 2012  
* author: Darren Maurer
* CEO/CIO/President
* Monarch Research International
* http://MonarchResearch.ca

using jQuery-1.7.2.min.js.php (caching enabled)
------------------------------------*/

//  Array of fileName to include in loader      
var urlsToLoadInOrder = ["js/file1.js","js/file2.js","js/file3.js"];

function ProcessDependency(urlArrayPointer) {

        if (urlArrayPointer >= urlsToLoadInOrder.length) {
            return;
        }

    var attemptedFile = urlsToLoadInOrder[urlArrayPointer];

    $.ajax({
       dataType: "script",
       url: attemptedFile,
       //Enable caching for performance, disable with 'cache: false'
       cache: true, 
       success: function() {
           //  code to execute on script load success
           urlArrayPointer++;
           ProcessDependency(urlArrayPointer);
       }
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
            //  Code to execute if script fails to load any further
            alert('FAILED Script Load '+attemptedFile +': '+exception);
            return false;
        });
}

//  Set pointer to zero and instantiate the loader
ProcessDependency(0);

//  All scripts successfully loaded in order, dependencies resolved
alert('loads complete');
```

Then just include these two lines on your main .html or .php page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php"></script>
<script src="ajaxDependencyLoader.js"> </script>
```

***AND VOILA!!!***  The easiest to use dependency loader I've found yet :)

The reason I use this method, is for dependency resolution between my scripts.  Each dependency set is defined as an array, and I loop through it, they load in order, and I'm happy :)